# jquery validate swedish character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm using jquery validate plugin and extending it like that

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noNumeric", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Letters only please");
```

Its working fine but not valid for swedish charecter.

Which regular expression can be used to test for characters (including swedish accented ones) but which also EXCLUDES (i.e. does not match) special characters like commas, dollars, hashes etc?

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok to use `\w` meaning any character found in a word - should work in most languages:

```
/^\w+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) javascript has no unicode support for regular expressions. So `\w` will not work.

But you can add the special characters to your character class like

```
/^[a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜß]+$/
```

I used the german ones I don't no the swedish.